# Comparing two lists which has lists within them

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class Cars and class Models. Car has many properties such as CarId and `List<Models>`. Models has has various properties such as ModelID, Color, Make. I have one list of Cars(coming from end user) call is A and then I have few sets lists of Cars(from DB) call it B . A has one list of Car where as B has multiple lists of Car, I want to compare these two including Models too.

I tried using [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) but that does not seem to be working

Sorry for not being clear. lets say
 list A has item carId = 1 and property Model has two items 1: ModelId =1, **color = black, make = 1999** and items 2: ModelId =3, color = white, make = 2004

list B has 2 items
 carId = 5 and Model has two items 1: ModelId =2, color = blue, make = 2000 and items 2: ModelId =3, color = white, make = 2010

carId = 7 and Model has two items 1: ModelId =5, **color = black, make = 1999** and items 2: ModelId =9, color = grey, make = 2011

in above example bolded values should be produced by comparer which I will store into new list.
appreciate help.
thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "compare"? do you mean finding out which Cars from A are not in B?

Comment: Could you give a small example of two lists and what your desired end result is?

Comment: added example. hopefully I am clear now....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to implement the IEqualityComparer, to add a custom compare function to your Models class