# Comparing Two group of lists

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing two lists which has lists within them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265850/comparing-two-lists-which-has-lists-within-them)

I have a class Cars and class Models. Car has many properties such as CarId and `List<Models>`. Models has has various properties such as ModelID, Color, Make. I have one list of Cars (coming from end user) call it A and then I have few lists of Cars(from DB) call it B . A has one list of Car where as B has multiple lists of Car, I want to compare these two including Models too.

I tried using [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) but that does not seem to be working.

Let's say list A has a Car and two Models

```
Car
carId = 1 
Models
  Model  
  ModelId = 1
  **color = black
  make = 1999** 

  Model  
  ModelId = 3
  color = white
  make = 2004
```

List B has 2 items

```
Car
carId = 5
Models
  Model 
  ModelId = 2
  color = blue
  make = 2000 

  Model
  ModelId = 3
  color = white
  make = 2010

Car
carId = 7
Models
  Model
  ModelId = 5
  **color = black
  make = 1999** 

  Model
  ModelId = 9
  color = grey
  make = 2011
```

In above example bolded(marked as **) values should be produced by comparer which I will store into new list.

New List would be

Car
    carId = 7
    Models
      Model
      ModelId = 5
      **color = black
      make = 1999**

Appreciate help. thanks!

Comment: "in above example bolded values should" except there are no bolded values.

Comment: Please add a third list that shows exactly what you want as output.

Comment: Added Bolded as ** values and expected output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`A.Except(B)` will not work unless the items from `A` are the same objects as the items in `B`. Either you need to implement `Equals` in your class hierarchy, or create an [`IEqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and pass that to the [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) call

Answer (score 0):

Check out IEnumerable.Union, this might help solve your issue

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx

It will combine 2 sets and not include duplicates.